# Is there a log shipper for logstash that does not require Java?

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

We have various windows boxes which we want to aggregate IIS (and other) logs from. Logstash with elasticsearch seems like the direction to take.

However we do not want java installed on the server machines (the central logstash one is fine obviously). Is there a shipper that does not require java that will get logs into logstash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of shippers these days. You can use standard syslog to send logs to logstash, there are some implementations for Windows availabe. You can take also look into the fluentd documentation which mentions nxlog (http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/windows).

Logstash itself doesn't care too much how you get the logs into its system. You can use redis, tcp, syslog, udp... whatever is most convenient or available. Please take a look into all supported input types on http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out for Fluentd. With Fluentd, you actually don't have to distinguish shipper from aggregator because it's all pretty lightweight (30-40MB memory) and supports file-based buffering (= no need for redis-like queues).

Answer (score 1):

The most common non-logstash shipper is certainly logstash-forwarder.  It's written in go, and was designed as a small-footprint, ssl-enabled shipper.  It has nearly no options.

Depending on your requirements (redis, etc), you might also look at beaver.